# Magento Reindex Prices error

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, reindex

I am not really sure what got changed but for some reason now i cant reindex my product prices... this is the error that my log is throwing me, any help would be much appreciated.

```
> 2015-09-08T14:10:10+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id`, `inner`.`tax_class_id`, `inner`.`orig_price`, `inner`.`price`, `inner`.`min_price`, MAX(inner.max_price) AS `max_price`, `inner`.`tier_price`, `inner`.`base_tier` FROM (SELECT e.entity_id AS `entity_id`, pi.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, cw.website_id AS `website_id`, pi.tax_class_id AS `tax_class_id`, pi.price AS `orig_price`, pi.final_price AS `price`, pi.final_price AS `min_price`, pi.final_price AS `max_price`, pi.tier_price AS `tier_price`, pi.tier_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = l.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AS `pi` ON ce.entity_id = pi.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON pi.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = ce.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (e.type_id='configurable') ORDER BY IF(IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 1,cisi.is_in_stock, 1), 1, 0) DESC, pi.final_price ASC, pi.price ASC) AS `inner` GROUP BY `inner`.`entity_id`,
    `inner`.`customer_group_id`,
    `inner`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)
Trace: #0 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(133): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(48): OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#8 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#13 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#14 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
2015-09-08T14:11:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id`, `inner`.`tax_class_id`, `inner`.`orig_price`, `inner`.`price`, `inner`.`min_price`, MAX(inner.max_price) AS `max_price`, `inner`.`tier_price`, `inner`.`base_tier` FROM (SELECT e.entity_id AS `entity_id`, pi.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, cw.website_id AS `website_id`, pi.tax_class_id AS `tax_class_id`, pi.price AS `orig_price`, pi.final_price AS `price`, pi.final_price AS `min_price`, pi.final_price AS `max_price`, pi.tier_price AS `tier_price`, pi.tier_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = l.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AS `pi` ON ce.entity_id = pi.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON pi.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = ce.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (e.type_id='configurable') ORDER BY IF(IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 1,cisi.is_in_stock, 1), 1, 0) DESC, pi.final_price ASC, pi.price ASC) AS `inner` GROUP BY `inner`.`entity_id`,
    `inner`.`customer_group_id`,
    `inner`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)
Trace: #0 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(133): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(48): OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#8 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#13 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#14 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
2015-09-08T14:19:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id`, `inner`.`tax_class_id`, `inner`.`orig_price`, `inner`.`price`, `inner`.`min_price`, MAX(inner.max_price) AS `max_price`, `inner`.`tier_price`, `inner`.`base_tier` FROM (SELECT e.entity_id AS `entity_id`, pi.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, cw.website_id AS `website_id`, pi.tax_class_id AS `tax_class_id`, pi.price AS `orig_price`, pi.final_price AS `price`, pi.final_price AS `min_price`, pi.final_price AS `max_price`, pi.tier_price AS `tier_price`, pi.tier_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = l.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AS `pi` ON ce.entity_id = pi.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON pi.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = ce.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (e.type_id='configurable') ORDER BY IF(IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 1,cisi.is_in_stock, 1), 1, 0) DESC, pi.final_price ASC, pi.price ASC) AS `inner` GROUP BY `inner`.`entity_id`,
    `inner`.`customer_group_id`,
    `inner`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)
Trace: #0 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(133): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(48): OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#8 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#13 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#14 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
2015-09-08T14:22:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id`, `inner`.`tax_class_id`, `inner`.`orig_price`, `inner`.`price`, `inner`.`min_price`, MAX(inner.max_price) AS `max_price`, `inner`.`tier_price`, `inner`.`base_tier` FROM (SELECT e.entity_id AS `entity_id`, pi.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, cw.website_id AS `website_id`, pi.tax_class_id AS `tax_class_id`, pi.price AS `orig_price`, pi.final_price AS `price`, pi.final_price AS `min_price`, pi.final_price AS `max_price`, pi.tier_price AS `tier_price`, pi.tier_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = l.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AS `pi` ON ce.entity_id = pi.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON pi.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = ce.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (e.type_id='configurable') ORDER BY IF(IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 1,cisi.is_in_stock, 1), 1, 0) DESC, pi.final_price ASC, pi.price ASC) AS `inner` GROUP BY `inner`.`entity_id`,
    `inner`.`customer_group_id`,
    `inner`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)
Trace: #0 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(133): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(48): OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#8 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#13 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#14 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
2015-09-08T14:23:53+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` SELECT `inner`.`entity_id`, `inner`.`customer_group_id`, `inner`.`website_id`, `inner`.`tax_class_id`, `inner`.`orig_price`, `inner`.`price`, `inner`.`min_price`, MAX(inner.max_price) AS `max_price`, `inner`.`tier_price`, `inner`.`base_tier` FROM (SELECT e.entity_id AS `entity_id`, pi.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, cw.website_id AS `website_id`, pi.tax_class_id AS `tax_class_id`, pi.price AS `orig_price`, pi.final_price AS `price`, pi.final_price AS `min_price`, pi.final_price AS `max_price`, pi.tier_price AS `tier_price`, pi.tier_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = l.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AS `pi` ON ce.entity_id = pi.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON pi.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.stock_id = cis.stock_id AND cisi.product_id = ce.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = ce.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 96 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (e.type_id='configurable') ORDER BY IF(IF(cisi.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND cisi.manage_stock = 1,cisi.is_in_stock, 1), 1, 0) DESC, pi.final_price ASC, pi.price ASC) AS `inner` GROUP BY `inner`.`entity_id`,
    `inner`.`customer_group_id`,
    `inner`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`)
Trace: #0 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(133): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(48): OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#8 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#13 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#14 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/romano6/public_html/demo/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Comment: It looks like it is throwing an error near `OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts` - did you recently upgrade this extension? Did you install any other extensions? Did you remove a previously installed extension? More information would help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As you are running OrganiceInternet Simple Configurable Products you need to apply a fix to it's code. The file:

> /app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php

Needs a few lines of extra code. Here is a replacement [file](http://pastebin.com/spVj88T4).

The issue is described here:
http://teition.com/price-indexer-will-not-re-index-in-magento/